# What could be the reason for a socket error "[Errno 9] Bad file descriptor"

Tags: python, sockets, python-2.7

I have a complex python (2.7.3) script which is trying to open a socket connection via

```
self.socket.close()
# doing something else
self.socket.connect((host, port))
```

but all I get is the following socket error:

```
error: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

The `host:port` accepts connections as I have verified this with `nc host port` manually. So what could be the possible reasons I get this error for opening a connection to the given port, which actually works?

I cannot and will not post the full script as it is too complex and irrelavent for this question. I just would like to know all possible reasons for this error, and how to check them and fix them.

Comment: Read the documentation for `socket.close()`. You cannot reuse it in any operation (including `connect`) once you close it. It needs to be reinitialized with a call to `socket.socket`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You will need to create a new socket object. Maybe `self.socket = socket.socket()` after closing the previous socket and before connecting.