# Python Portscanner

Tags: python, port, port-scanning

I've been writing a little script to scan a host for a specific port range by choice and ran into some weird error while trying to test the custom range:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/root/Desktop/ScannerV1Beta.py", line 74, in <module>
   result = s.connect_ex((targetIP, i))

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
   return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 170, in _dummy
   raise error(EBADF, 'Bad file descriptor')

   socket.error: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python

from socket import *


target = raw_input('Enter host or ip to scan: ')
targetIP = gethostbyname(target)
choice = raw_input('Please Choose the port range:\n (1) 1 - 1023 \n (2) 1024 - 5000 \n (3) 5000 - 10000 \n (c) custom \n ')
print 'Starting scan on host ', targetIP



if choice == '1':
    for i in range(1, 134):
        s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)

        result = s.connect_ex((targetIP, i))

        if(result == 0) :
            print 'Port %d: OPEN' % (i)
        else:
            print 'Port %d: CLOSED' % (i)
        s.close()

    for i in range(133, 1024):
        s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)

        result = s.connect_ex((targetIP, i))

        if(result == 0) :
            print 'Port %d: OPEN' % (i)
        else:
            print 'Port %d: CLOSED' % (i)

        s.close()



elif choice == '2':
    for i in range(1024, 5000):
        s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)

        result = s.connect_ex((targetIP, i))

        if(result == 0) :
            print 'Port %d: OPEN' % (i)
        else:
            print 'Port %d: CLOSED' % (i)

        s.close()

if choice == '3':
    for i in range(5000, 10000):
        s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)

        result = s.connect_ex((targetIP, i))

        if(result == 0) :
            print 'Port %d: OPEN' % (i)
        else:
            print 'Port %d: CLOSED' % (i)

        s.close()
if choice == 'c':
    firstPort = raw_input('Please specify starting Port: ')
    endPort = raw_input('Please specify ending Port(max 65535): ')
    endPort = int(endPort)
    firstPort = int(firstPort)
    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)

    if firstPort in range(0, 65535):
        if endPort in range(0, 65535):
            for i in range(firstPort, endPort):
                result = s.connect_ex((targetIP, i))
                if(result == 0) :
                    print 'Port %d: OPEN' % (i)
                else:
                    print 'Port %d: CLOSED' % (i)
                s.close()
        else:
            print('Error: Ports not in range!!')
            s.close()
    else:
        print('Error:Ports not in range!!')
        s.close()
```

i know the way i handled and converted the chosen ports is not the best option but i was quite on a run there. What might be the possible cause for said errors?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What could be the reason for a socket error "\[Errno 9\] Bad file descriptor"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17207051/what-could-be-the-reason-for-a-socket-error-errno-9-bad-file-descriptor)

Comment: That did quite help yeah. But i still don't get why it's doing so, I'm not closing the socket immediately, it get's closed when the if function hit the range limit(atleast that it's supposed to do).

Answer (score 0):

In the last "for" you are closing socket, but don't creating new. Rewrite the last "for" cycle as:

```
for i in range(firstPort, endPort):
    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    result = s.connect_ex((targetIP, i))
    if(result == 0) :
        print 'Port %d: OPEN' % (i)
    else:
        print 'Port %d: CLOSED' % (i)
    s.close()
```

Answer (score -1):

## portscanner

---

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
import socket
import os
import platform
def cls():
    if platform.system() == 'Linux':
      os.system("clear")
    else:
        os.system("cls")
def main():
    cls()
    print("---[ Port Scanner ]---\n")
    host = input("Enter Host: ")
    print("\n")
    ports = [21,22,23,25,80,111,443] # ports
    for port in ports:
       s = socket.socket()
       ch = s.connect_ex((host,port))
       if ch.status_code == 200:
         print(f"Port: {port} Open!")
       else:
           print(f"Port: {port} Filter!")
if __name__ == '__main__':
  try:
     main()
  except (KeyboardInterrupt,EOFError):
      print("\nStop !!!")
      exit()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. See How to Answer. 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please explain how this piece of code works. Also, this hasn't explained why the Johnny's code is not working.