# Python ssl default context throws bad file descriptor error

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, openssl

I have a very strange issue with `ssl` library in Python.

My Python version is 3.5.2.

All I'm doing is running the following three lines of code:

```
import ssl
ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context(purpose=ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)
ssl_context.load_cert_chain(certfile=r'C:\_del\publicCert.pem', 
                            keyfile=r'C:\_del\privateKey.pem')
```

Calling the last line throws an error:

```
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

I was trying to find information on `ssl` library and "Bad file descriptor" error, but all I found were issues where connection was already established. I think in my case, it must have something to do either with the settings or the files themselves, since when I `create_default_context` and `load_cert_chain` there's no connection to the server yet.

My certificate/key files have the following structure:

privateKey.pem

```
Bag Attributes
localKeyID: ...
friendlyName: ...

Key Attributes: <No Attributes>
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: ...
DEK-Info: ...
...key content...
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

publicCert.pem

```
Bag Attributes
localKeyID: ...
friendlyName: ...
subject=...
issuer=...
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
... certificate content ...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Has anyone encountered such issue?
Is it possible that the certificate I'm using is not compatible with OpenSSL version (0.9.8r)? The certificate uses SHA256 algorithm.

Additional information:
When I'm using openssl and try to verify the certificate PEM file:
`openssl verify C:\_del\certfile.pem`
I'm getting the following error:
`error 20 at 0 depth lookup:unable to get local issuer certificate`

Comment: The certificate file `publicCert.cert` must be a singe file of format `PEM`. do you know what is format of your `cert` file?

Comment: Please post your complete code. it does not help a lot. I think you are not opening socket and trying to connect with it.

Comment: may be this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17207051/what-could-be-the-reason-for-a-socket-error-errno-9-bad-file-descriptor

Comment: What is in the original post is my complete code. It is really just 3 lines. Importing ssl library, creating default context (with Client Authentication purpose) and trying to load certificate and key. Both publicCert.cert and privateKey.key are in fact pem files. I think there is no connection within these 3 lines.

Comment: you just want to make context? and nothing else? This application makes no sense. what do you want to achieve?

Comment: can you post your certificate and key? just open both in any text editor and paste here with your question.

Comment: I want to send a post request using requests library. But I'm getting Bad file descriptor error. This error is thrown, when requests is calling load_cert_chain. Therefore I only showed these 3 lines because in the end this is where the problem is. I think I cannot show a private key on SO.

Comment: how are you certain that error is on this line? you can make a sample private key and a sample certitificate for test. that key you can also share here. One thing to note is that there is no file descriptor in these two lines. I am getting the feeling that error is occurring where you are sending the post request. If you cannot share your code and keys here, no body can help you. good luck then.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue myself, and couldn't find any answers online.  Finally, I figured it out.

If you open your key file, and either:

1. The first line looks like this: `-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----`
2. The `Proc-Type` contains the string `Encrypted` (which may be the case for OP, although he didn't tell us the `Proc-Type`)

...Then you must provide the `password` argument to the `load_cert_chain()` call in order to decrypt the private key.  If you don't supply a password, you can get the `Bad file descriptor` error.